# Difference between the two methods of clearing cache in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, rm

There are two methods we can clear cache in symfony application:

`app/console cache:clear [--env=prod]`

&

`rm -rf app/cache/*`

What is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command `app/console cache:clear` deletes the cache directory as well as `rm` but it also runs warmup phase, where it re-creates cache fiels so I doesn't need to be created by the first request that arrives (see `no-warmup` option).